# Oracle update statement using multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to update price of my products, using another table which has product material and number of that material

my tables are produkt (`PRODUKTID` int, `NAZOV` varchar(47), `VYROBNA_CENA` int)
TABLE material (`MATERIALID` int, `CENA` numeric);
TABLE zlozenie (`PRODUKTKID` int, `MATERIALID` int, `MNOZSTVO` int);

what i am trying to do is to put sum(ZLOZENIE.MNOZSTVO*MATERIAL.CENA) to column `VYROBNA_CENA`

i have two selects that are returning same column, but i am not sure how to use update to transfer values from one to another

first one - calculated price of products

```
select   PRODUKT.NAZOV as NAZOV, sum(ZLOZENIE.MNOZSTVO*MATERIAL.CENA) as celkova
from MATERIAL, PRODUKT, ZLOZENIE 
where   ZLOZENIE.MATERIALID=MATERIAL.MATERIALID
 and     PRODUKT.PRODUKTID=ZLOZENIE.PRODUKTKID
group by PRODUKT.NAZOV
order by PRODUKT.NAZOV
```

second one is table produkt with empty price(cena), and i would like to put results from sum to column cena

```
select  PRODUKT.NAZOV, PRODUKT.vyrobna_cena
from PRODUKT 
order by PRODUKT.NAZOV
```

sql fiddle with tables and queries http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e183f/2

thanks

Comment: you mean like this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618703/update-query-using-subquery-in-sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618703/update-query-using-subquery-in-sql-server)

Comment: @benji please note that this article is oracle and your link is sql server.  There may be a more specific way to handle this based on platform.  Additionally your link does not show how to handle aggregation.

Comment: @paqogomez but isn't it the same concept? `update table set column = subquery`?

Comment: @benji - same concept but Oracle doesn't support INNER JOIN syntax in UpDATEs (although it would be highly neat if it did)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO produkt p
  USING 
(
  SELECT ZLOZENIE.PRODUKTKID, SUM(ZLOZENIE.MNOZSTVO*MATERIAL.CENA) AS celkova
    FROM MATERIAL, ZLOZENIE 
    WHERE   ZLOZENIE.MATERIALID=MATERIAL.MATERIALID
    GROUP BY ZLOZENIE.PRODUKTKID
) s
ON (p.PRODUKTID = s.PRODUKTKID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET VYROBNA_CENA = s.celkova;
```

Although I would always use join syntax

```
MERGE INTO produkt p
  USING 
(
  SELECT ZLOZENIE.PRODUKTKID, SUM(ZLOZENIE.MNOZSTVO*MATERIAL.CENA) as celkova
    FROM MATERIAL
      JOIN ZLOZENIE ON ZLOZENIE.MATERIALID=MATERIAL.MATERIALID
    GROUP BY ZLOZENIE.PRODUKTKID
) s
ON (p.PRODUKTID = s.PRODUKTKID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET VYROBNA_CENA = s.celkova
```

Answer (score -1):

Following work is based on your sql fiddle and mysql database.

Change all the decimal columns in your creation scripts from integers to decimal. Following are the updated creation scripts

```
CREATE TABLE produkt
    (`PRODUKTID` int, `NAZOV` varchar(47), `VYROBNA_CENA` decimal(10,2));

CREATE TABLE zlozenie
    (`PRODUKTKID` int, `MATERIALID` int, `MNOZSTVO` decimal(10,5));

CREATE TABLE material
    (`MATERIALID` int, `CENA` decimal(10,2));
```

sqlfiddle with updated tables and queries : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0242f/6

Query to update the produckt table

```
update produkt INNER JOIN
(select  ZLOZENIE.PRODUKTKID,sum(ZLOZENIE.MNOZSTVO*MATERIAL.CENA) as celkova
from MATERIAL, ZLOZENIE 
where   ZLOZENIE.MATERIALID=MATERIAL.MATERIALID
group by ZLOZENIE.PRODUKTKID) ZM
on produkt.PRODUKTKID = ZM.PRODUKTKID
set produkt.VYROBNA_CENA = ZM.celkova
```

Let me know if this is not what you are after

Comment: thanks, i am getting ORA-00971: missing SET keyword error. i will try to find out where is problem..

Comment: MySQL syntax is different from Oracle syntax.  So this Solution won't work, alas.

Comment: Sevdah, Are you not using MySQL?