# Update table from itself, but only top result

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

So if we have a table with the following:

```
Id INT
EventDate DATETIME
NextDate DATETIME
UserId INT
```

I want to update the next date value from the same table and set the `NextDate` value to the date of the next entry related to that user.

Below is the basic query, but I'm not sure how to tell it to update it from the next occurring `EventDate`

```
UPDATE 
EVENTS
SET
NextDate = n.EventDate
FROM 
EVENTS AS n
WHERE
EVENTS.UserId = n.UserId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `lead()` function (available in SQL Server 2012+):

```
with toupdate as (
      select e.*,
             lead(eventdate) over (partition by userid order by eventdate) as next_eventdate
      from e
     )
update toupdate
    set nextdate = next_eventdate;
```

Note:  this should be much more efficient than alternative methods using joins, correlated subqueries, or `apply`.

Comment: I was not aware of this function (I used to code for SQL Server 2008) but it is designed exactly for this task and should be used instead of my answer if it's available. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213125.aspx

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2012, so I changed the answer to this one.

Answer (score 3):

You have to either join this table to itself, effectively behaving like there are two tables, or select the next date for each record in a subquery. Your query will probably look something like this:

```
UPDATE EVENTS
SET e.NextDate = (
  SELECT TOP 1 n.EventDate
  FROM EVENTS AS n
  WHERE e.UserId = n.UserId
  AND n.EventDate > e.EventDate
  ORDER BY n.EventDate ASC)
FROM EVENTS AS e
```

It may not be 100% correct, as I haven't used a windows SQL server in a while. The basic idea is the same as joining the table to another table, except you join it to the same table.

See this answer for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14618713/1160540

Comment: +1 For the self join. Another thing, In a SELECT statement, always use an ORDER BY clause with the TOP clause. This is the only way to predictably indicate which rows are affected by TOP.

Comment: @Ephraim I had that in mind when I started writing, but forgot to put it in! I'll update my answer...

Comment: I hadn't thought about this approach, that's easy!