# SQL Select to Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert this `SELECT` statement to an `UPDATE` statement but it's too hard. I don't even know if I can keep `INNER JOIN`s while updating, so I think I need some help from an SQL genius.

I need to update my customer ID on liste_objectif where it's NULL, and I have this id on customers table (by the mail)

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM liste_objectifs l
INNER JOIN customers c ON ( l.email = c.customer_email ) 
WHERE c.customer_id
IN (
    SELECT customer
    FROM newsletters_inscriptions
    WHERE liste
    IN ( 786, 878, 874, 875, 876, 877 )
)
AND c.customer_id NOT 
IN (
    SELECT customer
    FROM newsletters_blacklists
    WHERE newsletter =1
)
ORDER BY  `l`.`email` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Thanks !

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to update? What are you trying to set it to? What have you tried so far? Which actual flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: I shoulda say it sry, i'm using MYSQL

Comment: Which table and field to be change?

Comment: I need to update my customer ID on liste_objectif where it's NULL, and I have this id on customers table (by the mail)

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618703/update-query-using-subquery-in-sql-server

Comment: Thank you @Kaiser this was really helpful !

Comment: @DERETPierre-Yves you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes close:

```
update liste_objectifs l join
       customers c 
       on l.email = c.customer_email
    set l.customer_id = c.customer_id
where c.customer_id (SELECT customer
                     FROM newsletters_inscriptions
                     WHERE liste IN ( 786, 878, 874, 875, 876, 877 )
                    ) and
      c.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer
                            FROM newsletters_blacklists
                            WHERE newsletter = 1
                           ) and
      l.customer_id is null;
```

If you actually need `order by` and `limit`, then the query will need to be more complicated.  Those are not supported for multi-table updates.

Comment: Thanks this was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
Update liste_objectifs l
INNER JOIN customers c ON ( l.email = c.customer_email          )
  set l.customer_id=c.id
 WHERE c.customer_id
 IN (
SELECT customer
FROM newsletters_inscriptions
WHERE liste
IN ( 786, 878, 874, 875, 876, 877 )
)
AND c.customer_id NOT 
IN (
 SELECT customer
 FROM newsletters_blacklists
 WHERE newsletter =1
)
and customer_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN in update this way ( i don't know the name of you column to set in liste_objectifs so i named  it your_customer_id_column)

```
  UPDATE liste_objectifs l
  INNER JOIN FROM customers c   ON l.email = c.customer_email  
  SET  liste_objectifs.your_customer_id_column  = c.id
  WHERE c.customer_id
  IN (
      SELECT customer
      FROM newsletters_inscriptions
      WHERE liste
      IN ( 786, 878, 874, 875, 876, 877 )
  )
  AND c.customer_id NOT 
  IN (
      SELECT customer
      FROM newsletters_blacklists
      WHERE newsletter =1
  )
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer!